# Difficulties making a tkinter-based chat that looks like a apple window

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, chat

I'm having trouble making a round button and making it look good.

I need help trying to make a tkinter chat that looks as close as it can to a apple window (mac os). I already got all the sockets done on a other file i just need to make it look better.
Here's is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
root=Tk()
root.title('Chat server')
root.geometry("600x600")
#####


####
person = input('Who are you chatting with: ')
label = Label (root, text='Chat with ' + person )
label.grid(row=2,column=1)
frame=Frame(root, width=600, height=600, bg='blue')
frame.grid(row=3,column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

If you want the sockets code:

server:

```
import socket
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.title('Chat server')
root.geometry("600x600")
frame=Frame(root, width=600, height=200, bg='blue')

s=socket.socket()
print('Socket created')
port=12345
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
s.bind(('',port))
print("socket bound to %s" %(port))
history=[]
while True:
    s.listen(5)
    print("socket is listening")
    while True:
        g, addr = s.accept()
        print('Got connection from', addr)
        print('Connected')
        break

    while True:
        x = input('Friend: ')
        g.send(x.encode())
        data = g.recv(1024)
        history.append[data]
        print("Friend: ", repr(data))
    root.mainloop()
```

Heres client:

```
# client.py
import socket
host='192.168.1.17'  # server side ip address
port=12345
print('Finding...')
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port))
while 1:
    message=input("Say something to Friend: : ")
    s.send(message.encode())
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print('Friend: ', repr(data))

s.close()
```

Comment: Round buttons? I dont think there is actually an inbuilt way with `tkinter` to do it, rather use an image with the button to get rounded button effect.

Answer (score 0):

So, Tkinter uses the default skin of the available os as far as I know. So it will look closer to MacOs, IOs when you run your python code on a mac. However, you can put custom graphics on buttons etc. and "fake" a MacOS look. Have a look at this Stackoverflow answer:

[Tkinter custom create buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054156/tkinter-custom-create-buttons)